# Multiple directives [directive#1, directive#2] asking for isolated scope on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to build a new directive on top of an already existing directive but I am halted in my proces. When loading the page I'm facing the following error:

> Multiple directives [directive#1, directive#2] asking for isolated scope on `<easymodal title="Test-Title" text="Text-Text" oncancel="show = false" onok="alert();">`

The base directive looks like this:

```
Rohan.directive('easymodal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
//      priority: 200,
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            showModal: "=show",
            callback: "=closeFunction",
            dismissable: '&'
        },
        template:
            '<div data-ng-show="showModal" class="modal-container">' +
                '<div class="modal-body">' +
                    '<div class="title"><span data-translate></span><a data-ng-show="dismissable" data-ng-click="dismiss()">x</a></div>' +
                    '<div data-ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-backdrop" data-ng-click="dismiss()"></div>' +
            '</div>'
    };
});
```

And my wrapper directive looks like this:

```
Rohan.directive('easydialog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {title: '@',
            text: '@',
            onOk: '&',
            onCancel: '&'},
        replace: true,
        template:
            '<easymodal>' +
                '{{text}} ' +
                '<hr>' +
                '<button ng-click="{{onCancel}}" value="Cancel"' +
                '<button ng-click="{{onOk}}" value="Ok"' +
            '</easymodal>'
    };
});
```

My html looks like this:

```
<easydialog title="Test-Title" text="Text-Text" onCancel="show = false" onOk="alert();" />
```

At first I though my title attribute was conflicting so I removed that attribute in the html line and from my wrapper directive but it was not effective.

Comment: could you please set up fiddle

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to change your `easydialog` template and wrap `<easymodal>` in a `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks, I would've never guessed that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What is the problem in the first place and how is wrapping them in a div fixes it?

Comment: @mxa055 I believe Angular associates HTML elements to a scopes, and cannot associate a single HTML element to more than 1 scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem simply is that you're adding a `template` argument inside the `directive` as well as adding a resolving template tag named `<easydialog>` in your actual HTML template. You have the choose either the one or the other.